# What is the safe way and best-practice to set a state in parent hierarchy in React to stay DRY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this scenario:

An admin panel that has a sidebar and a content.

Sidebar contains menu and each item that user clicks, a component would be shown in the content area.

The content is a `Router` that changes the component based on URL.

Let's say we have these components:

`Page1.jsx`
`Page2.jsx`
`Page3.jsx`

Each of the does some operation when gets loaded. Each does it inside `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // some operation inside PageN.jsx that takes some time
    // Here we should show a progress
}, [])
```

We can easily define a state in each `PageN.jsx` and based on that return a progress or the actual component:

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState()

return progress
   ?
   <div>Loading...</div>
   :
   <div>Actual component</div>
```

This however is inefficient for an application with 100 pages and kills DRY and also introduces a lot of inconsistencies. Each page might show a different loading component, etc.

One way is to lift-up the `progress` state to the parent element `Router` or event the `App` itself. Then pass it down the hierarchy.

```
const PageN = ({ setContentProgress }) => {

    // now I can call parent's setContentProgress
```

But it soon gets into the famous [Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178).

So, what is the safe approach here? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest you to use context API, to simply build some layout context on top of your sidebar and content area.
Recently I implemented something similar for my personal project where I decided that I want to implement linear progress bar like YouTube has (red line progressing below the header), so the only option for me was to create layout context which will handle progress and then in its children I would simply use exposed actions from context itself, in order to update progress.

I did it in this way:

```
interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const initialState = {
  displayProgressBar: false,
  progressPercentage: 0
};

const PROGRES_BAR_TRANSITION = 300; // ms
let timeout: undefined | NodeJS.Timeout;

const Layout = ({ children }: IProps) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [context, setContext] = useState(initialState);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    setContext(initialState);

    return () => {
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [pathname]);

  const setLayoutProgressVisiblity = useCallback((isVisible: boolean) => {
    if (!isVisible)
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setContext((p) => ({ ...p, displayProgressBar: isVisible }));
      }, PROGRES_BAR_TRANSITION);
    else setContext((p) => ({ ...p, displayProgressBar: isVisible }));
  }, []);

  const setLayoutProgressPercentage = useCallback(
    (percentage: number) =>
      setContext((p) => ({ ...p, progressPercentage: percentage })),
    []
  );

  const contextActions =
    useMemo<ILayoutContext>(() => ({ setLayoutProgressPercentage, setLayoutProgressVisiblity }),
    [setLayoutProgressPercentage, setLayoutProgressVisiblity]);

  const goToHomepage = useCallback(() => {
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }, [navigate]);

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={contextActions}>
      <div className="app-container p-relative overflow-auto">
        <div>{/** HERE YOU CAN PUT HEADER */}</div>
        {context.displayProgressBar && (
          <HeaderProgressBar progress={context.progressPercentage} />
        )}
        <div className=" py-4 flex-fill overflow-auto">
          {<div className="container h-100">{children}</div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Beside this, I created one custom hook in order to use it whenever I want to access  layout actions:

```
 export const useLayoutContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(LayoutContext);

  if (!context)
    throw new Error(
      "No LayoutContext.Provider found when calling useLayoutContext."
    );

  return context;
};
```

And finally it is very easy to update progress within any element which is inside LayoutContext. Simple as this:

```
const { setLayoutProgressPercentage, setLayoutProgressVisiblity } =
useLayoutContext();
```

Comment: This seems to be a good way. But this is possible, only because you do not show **progress** instead of the component. You show/hide progress as another component alongside the main content.

Comment: It is up to you how you want to handle progress, you can expose `progressPercentage` through context provider value, and then you can handle progress in any component inside layout context.